# What is the meaning of the sum and the Sigma notation in the Goodfellow et al. simplified version of the back-propagation algorithm?

Tags: neural-networks, notation, backpropagation

In the Goodfellow et al. book "Deep Learning" there is a simplified version of the back-propagation algorithm (*Algorithm 6.2, Chapter 6*).

Authors state that the chain rule with respect to some scalar output $u^{(n)}$ is the next:
$$\frac{\partial u^{(n)}}{\partial u^{(j)}}= \sum_{i:j\in Pa(u^{(i)})}\frac{\partial u^{(n)}}{\partial u^{(i)}}\frac{\partial u^{(i)}}{\partial u^{(j)}}$$

*According to authors notes*:

- $Pa(u^{(i)})$ means the parents of $u^{(i)}$
- $u^{(1)}$ to $u^{(n_i)}$ inputs nodes to an output $u^{(n)}$ node

What does the notation of the Sigma index mean in this context? How can I interpret the colon symbol there? Why do we use the sum at all to calculate the partial derivative of the output?